# How to exhange data between 2 iPads?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ipad

i'm trying to establish real time connection between 2 ipads.

so far, i've done bluetooth already, but i want to do it over the internet as well. can someone point me in the right direction for the best way to do it?

thx in advance.

Comment: What kind of data are you sending? Big chunks? Little pieces?

Comment: (NSDictionary *), or maybe bytes, limited to around 1kb

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/

If you want the app to handle http requests you could try this. Implementing it will be quite a trick, so good luck and have fun!

Comment: That said, this is just one way to go about it.

Comment: what about more persistant forms of connection? from what I understand this has to go through a 3 way handshake everytime a request is sent.

Comment: NSStream, along with NSInputStream and NSOutputStream is probably what you're after!

Comment: huh? can pass me the link to that question?

Comment: No I mean that he asked you a question on this thread! Haha. He asked what type of data you are sending. Big chunks or little pieces?